# iOS : How to get a view's bounds that layout use Masonry

Tags: ios, masonry

I have a question.
I use masonry layout the statusBar. Now I want to add a CAGradientLayer to the statusBar. So I need to get the statusBar.bounds. But the bounds is zero. And the masonry can't addConstraint for a layer. Thank you very much!
this is my code:

```
self.statusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:self.statusBar];
    [_statusBar mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.equalTo(self);
        make.height.equalTo(@(20));
        make.top.left.equalTo(@(0));
    }];
    [self setStatusBarColorWithStartColor:[UIColor blackColor] endColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

- (void)setStatusBarColorWithStartColor:(UIColor *)startColor endColor:(UIColor *)endColor
{
    // init CAGradientLayer
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.statusBar.frame));
gradientLayer.frame = self.statusBar.bounds; // bound is zero
[self.statusBar.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];

// set gradient colors
gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)startColor.CGColor, (__bridge id)endColor.CGColor];

// set star and end point
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);

// optional set locations
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
 [self.statusBar mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(@(0));
    make.top.equalTo(@(0));
    make.right.equalTo(@(0));
    make.height.equalTo(@(20));
  }];
```

Comment: I tried but the bounds is still zero. Also thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get the right frame and bounds through overriding view's method **layoutSubviews** or view controller's **viewDidLayoutSubviews**. Be carefull these two selector will be invoked many times, and **viewDidLayoutSubviews** need call **[super viewDidLayoutSubviews]**.

Comment: Thank you. I have derived inspiration from your answer. Before  this code ,`gradientLayer.frame = self.statusBar.bounds; // bound is zero` ,I add `[self layoutIfNeeded];`.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Yahoho